# JScrollPane not working with JPanel and JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jscrollpane

For my code, I did something like:

```
Jframe frame = new JFrame();
JPanel panel = new JPanel();

JButton button = new JButton();
// after locating and resizing buttons...
panel.add(button);

// and after many codes about buttons and labels...

frame.add(panel);

JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(panel);
scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
frame.add(scroll);
```

As far as I know, this should be correct, but I can't scroll. **The gray bar inside the scroll bar is missing.**

Here is image for better idea of what's happening to my code.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the official tutorial about the scroll panes on https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html, they note about the policies:

> VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS
>
> HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS
>
> Always display the scroll bar. The knob disappears if the viewport is
>   large enough to show the whole client.

Comment: That's epic! Thank you for the best answer I could have ever asked for!

Comment: @Dory Take a look at [what should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).